# Pick image from sd card, resize the image and save it back to sd card

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am working on an application, in which I need to pick an image from `sd card` and show it in image view. Now I want the user to decrease/increase its width by clicking a button and then save it back to the sd card.

I have done the image picking and showing it on ui. But unable to find how to resize it.Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just yesterday i have done this

```
File dir=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
Bitmap b= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH_ORIGINAL_IMAGE);
Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 320, 480, false);

File file = new File(dir, "resize.png");
FileOutputStream fOut;
try {
    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
    fOut.flush();
    fOut.close();
    b.recycle();
    out.recycle();               
} catch (Exception e) {}
```

Also don't forget to recycle your `bitmaps`: It will save memory.

You can also get path of new created file String: `newPath=file.getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile()............this will throw OOM exception when opening images of big size, you need to use "options" in order to open and if you do so you will get a reduced version of the original image........

Comment: and i need to zoom out on the original image and save them and not on the altered image.......and i have noticed this in the gallery app itself.....i added some effects to the image of size 6.33 MB and after effects the size was 507 KB........huge loss of information and i dont want that......

Comment: Its working fine but how to preserve the image quality.

Answer (score 13):

Solution without `OutOfMemoryException` in Kotlin

```
fun resizeImage(file: File, scaleTo: Int = 1024) {
    val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath, bmOptions)
    val photoW = bmOptions.outWidth
    val photoH = bmOptions.outHeight

    // Determine how much to scale down the image
    val scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / scaleTo, photoH / scaleTo)

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor

    val resized = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.absolutePath, bmOptions) ?: return
    file.outputStream().use {
        resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, it)
        resized.recycle()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using this method:

```
public static Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bitmapToScale, float newWidth, float newHeight) {   
if(bitmapToScale == null)
    return null;
//get the original width and height
int width = bitmapToScale.getWidth();
int height = bitmapToScale.getHeight();
// create a matrix for the manipulation
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// resize the bit map
matrix.postScale(newWidth / width, newHeight / height);

// recreate the new Bitmap and set it back
return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapToScale, 0, 0, bitmapToScale.getWidth(), bitmapToScale.getHeight(), matrix, true);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful library for this achievement: https://github.com/hkk595/Resizer

Answer (score 1):

Here my static method:

```
public static void resizeImageFile(File originalImageFile, File resizedImageFile, int maxSize) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
    Bitmap resizedBitmap;
    if (bitmap.getWidth() > bitmap.getHeight()) {
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, maxSize, maxSize * bitmap.getHeight() / bitmap.getWidth(), false);
    } else {
        resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, maxSize * bitmap.getWidth() / bitmap.getHeight(), maxSize, false);
    }

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
    try {
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(resizedImageFile);
        resizedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        bitmap.recycle();
        resizedBitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally use multitouch instead of using a button to increase/decrease width. [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/) an amazing library. Once the user decides to save the image, the image translation matrix must be stored persistently (in your sqlite database). Next time the user opens the image, you need to recall the matrix and apply it to your image.

I've actually done this before.