# Resizing an image in android

Tags: java, android, resize

I have some code where you can take an image from a folder and when a toggle button is on, the image will be resized and stored to another folder.

When I run this code using a toggle button the app crashes saying "Unfortunately MyApps has stopped".  This code is in Java and I want to run this program in android. How can I achieve this?

```
public class ImageTest 
    {
        private static int height;
        private static int width ;
        private static int IMG_HEIGHT=480;
        private static int IMG_WIDTH;

        public int image()
    {


        try{
            BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\image\\12.jpg"));
             width          = bimg.getWidth();
             height         = bimg.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Width:"+width+" and height:"+height);


            IMG_WIDTH = ((IMG_HEIGHT * width)/height);

            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("d:\\image\\12.jpg"));
            int type = originalImage.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : originalImage.getType();

            BufferedImage resizeImageJpg = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImageJpg, "jpg", new File("d:\\image\\12_jpg.jpg")); 

            BufferedImage resizeImagePng = resizeImage(originalImage, type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImagePng, "png", new File("d:\\image\\12_png.png")); 

            BufferedImage resizeImageHintJpg = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImageHintJpg, "jpg", new File("d:\\image\\12_hint_jpg.jpg")); 

            BufferedImage resizeImageHintPng = resizeImageWithHint(originalImage, type);
            ImageIO.write(resizeImageHintPng, "png", new File("d:\\image\\12_hint_png.png"));
            return 1;

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }

    }

        private static  BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage originalImage, int type)
        {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();

        return resizedImage;
        }

        private static BufferedImage resizeImageWithHint(BufferedImage originalImage, int type)
        {

        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
        g.dispose();    
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);

        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        return resizedImage;
        }   
    }
```

Comment: and where is it stopping? What exceptions are thrown?

Comment: can you please post your logcat output.

Comment: this code works fine in java

Comment: maybe file not found then, or some other issue.

Comment: ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\image\\12.jpg")); -- Is in Java.. Your Android system doesnt have this path. The same applies to Write operations as well... You have to put these images in "raw" folder and access these images... Remember, your android system is different from your Windows system..

Comment: 01-06 23:58:19.216: D/gralloc_goldfish(1208): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-06 23:58:21.416: W/dalvikvm(1208): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;)
01-06 23:58:21.416: E/dalvikvm(1208): Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.example.myapps.ImageTest.resizeImage
01-06 23:58:21.416: W/dalvikvm(1208): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 749 (Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;) in Lcom/example/myapps/ImageTest;

Comment: can anyone please give me the exact android code please

Comment: @user3167821 - Ya... Also, everything that runs in Java CANNOT run on Android...

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can try this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688982/pick-image-from-sd-card-resize-the-image-and-save-it-back-to-sd-card); as being a similar question to what you have asked. And regarding your code you cannot directly run java code in `Android`.

First refer above link and then try running.

Comment: You can even refer [link](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) for more basic details.