# how to reduce image Size without Quality break in android

Tags: android

```
                Bitmap bmp = getResizedBitmap(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length),
                        500);


public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int maxSize) {
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();

        float bitmapRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
        if (bitmapRatio > 0) {
            width = maxSize;
            height = (int) (width / bitmapRatio);
        } else {
            height = maxSize;
            width = (int) (height * bitmapRatio);
        }
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    }
```

This is my code Using getResizedBitmap i able to reduced image size but unable to keep its original quality  in android please tell me how to keep quality  Good so that image Size reduce and Quality should not bad  please suggest me !

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688982/pick-image-from-sd-card-resize-the-image-and-save-it-back-to-sd-card

Comment: createScaledBitmap where is this method @Moudiz

Comment: `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` ... it's inside the Bitmap object!!

Comment: But it show depricated

Comment: and will have to write code for reduced Size ?

Answer (score 1):

hi please try below code hope it meets which you want

```
public static Bitmap scaleImage(String p_path, int p_reqHeight, int p_reqWidth) throws Throwable
    {
        Bitmap m_bitMap = null;
        System.gc();
        File m_file = new File(p_path);
        if (m_file.exists())
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options m_bitMapFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_bitMapFactoryOptions);
            m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(m_bitMapFactoryOptions, p_reqHeight, p_reqWidth);
            m_bitMapFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            m_bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_bitMapFactoryOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Throwable(p_path + " not found or not a valid image");
        }
        return m_bitMap;
    }


    // Helper method
    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options p_options, int p_reqWidth, int p_reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int m_height = p_options.outHeight;
        final int m_width = p_options.outWidth;
        int m_inSampleSize = 1;
        if (m_height > p_reqHeight || m_width > p_reqWidth)
        {
            final int m_halfHeight = m_height / 2;
            final int m_halfWidth = m_width / 2;
            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((m_halfHeight / m_inSampleSize) > p_reqHeight && (m_halfWidth / m_inSampleSize) > p_reqWidth)
            {
                m_inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return m_inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: But i have to pass Bitmap and return Bitmap i dont have to pass String path coz  http://paste.ofcode.org/xuP42buQd3EiYFNWcJj4Ya here  is my code

Comment: But if your image is high resolution image then it will throw OutOfMemory error , so better to pass image path instead of Bitmap . use my code which i have sent which will never throw OOM exception