# Android: Resize Large Image from File to File

Tags: android, image, memory, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize large images (16MP) on Android down to smaller but still large (8MP) images.     I tried some approaches I've found on SO with sampled or scaled loads into memory,  but neither one of these sizes fits into a decoded bitmap in memory reliably.

Is there a way I go straight from input file to output file while using a minimal amount of memory?    Some sort of streaming decode/encode?

Comment: see thi: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688982/pick-image-from-sd-card-resize-the-image-and-save-it-back-to-sd-card

Comment: thanks calvin,  that still brings the scaled bitmap fully into memory